# Unitary transformation of column vectors

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Suppose we have a set of nonzero column vectors of complex numbers of the same height $n$. call them $C_i$. and we unitarily transform them into a set of column vectors $D_i$ with the same height $n$.

The transformation also has the condition that:

$D_{i,j} = k_{ij}\times C_{i,j}$, where $k$ is some matrix of $nxn$ real numbers. $C_{i,j}$ denotes the jth element of the column vector $C_i$, similarly with $D$.

EDIT: another condition

We know that $k_{ii} = 1$ for all $i$.

Prove the other elements of $k$ must be $\pm 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The unitary condition implies the norm of $D_i$ is the same as the norm of $C_i$. So, for each $i$, we have
$\sum_j k_{ij}^2 |C_{ij}|^2 = \sum_j |C_{ij}|^2$. So you see that $k_{ij}$ all being $\pm 1$ works. However, I think you need more conditions to assert that no other $k_{ij}$ will work. For instance, if all the $C_i$ are the zero vector, then any $k_{ij}$ will work.

Comment: I've included the condition that the vectors are nonzero.

Comment: @AmeetSharma I still do not think this is enough. If you only have a single column $C_1=(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})$ and the unitary transformation rotates it to $D_1=(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$, you see that $k_{11}=1/\sqrt{2}$ and $k_{12}=\sqrt{3/2}$ which are not $\pm 1$.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll add another condition.